# Elasticsearch NEST client datetime deserialization

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, serialization, deserialization, nest

I'm trying to deserialize my NEST document to datetime, but everything ends up being a `string` because I'm using `System.Object`:

```
var response = this.client.Search<object>(search);
```

The reason for this is because I'm searching multiple indices and I have to use `object` type. Since my whole application is returning `DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`.

I'd like NEST to deserialize datetime to `DateTime` type, so that my serializer can correctly serialize to `MicrosoftDateFormat` on API.